Using LED lamps on stage - adjusting brightness
I have some LED lanterns for stage use. They are fairly complex in that they have a flickering candle effect made by having a series of LEDs stuck to a central column (the candle) and a circuit of some kind that switches them on and off in a pattern.
The actual pattern is fairly irrelevant but they look good in an 'antiqued' casing and frosted glass.
Now, here's the thing. They worked well in a small performance space, but now we're moving the show to a larger theatre and we fear that the lights will be too dim for the larger space and auditorium; the audience is farther away.

Idea #1: We cannibalize one lamp to add the guts into the casing of a second unit. Each lamp currently has 3 x 1.5A batteries, so if we hooked the two sets of lamp gubbings to one 9V, they would both be as they were...yes?
BUT - idea #2 - could we then have a switch so that we could isolate ONE of the two candle components for when we don't need the extra bright light?
OR - idea #3 - is there any way in which they could run off the same battery (eg the 9v - which would make the packaging easier) and have a variable resistor to adjust the brightness. IN which case how would we spec that item?


Many ways to drive LEDs from 3X 1.5V cells as you've described - some ways don't combine nicely for a brighter effect. Similar to asking, "how do I combine two sub-critical masses of plutonium for something more impressive?" We'd like to know more about lamp gubbins.

The short answer is "no". What you are trying to do will not work for several reasons. It would make more sense to get a bigger candle/lantern. Or, put the internals of several candles in one lantern, leaving the power and controls of the individual candles independent.

Simply increasing the voltage from 4.5V to 9V will not make the lantern brighter - it's much more complicated than that.

The lamps run from 4.5 V, you want to put two in one lantern so you will get twice the light.
You can connect them in two ways, in series using a 9 V supply or in parallel using a 4.5 V supply.
If you connect them in series it will be more difficult to switch it between two lamps and one. With parallel that would be easy, so that’s an advantage of wiring them in parallel.
If you were thinking of using a standard 9 V battery you would have to take into consideration that they will typically be able to source less current than 1.5 V cells so they won’t last as long. You would need to determine the current draw of the lamps and how much current each type of battery can provide to see which arrangement will work best.
With a parallel connection there may be a problem if the lamps have different voltage drops, if they are just series connected LEDs they may be voltage sensitive and in parallel one may draw more current than the other giving them uneven brightness. You would need to try hooking two in parallel to one 4.5 V battery pack to see if they will work okay that way. That your lamps have a controller that flashes them pretty much rules out this being a problem though.
Either way, without increasing the amp hours of the batteries used you will get less run time, about half the time for parallel with 4.5 V and probably less than that for series with a 9 V battery.

Wait, what? The 9v wouldn't last as long as the 4.5v? Oh, if in series...gotcha.

So, one of the comments above suggests that simply duplicating the insides and duplicating the power-source is simplest. Could I then simply have them on the same switch? How would I know the effect (on the lamp unit) of running one off the 9v battery?

@PhilipHolden You don’t want to run just one on 9V, that’s the problem. Each one is presumptively designed to run on 4.5V, so you would need two in series for 9V, this makes switching one off difficult. Also the reason a 9V would have less run time is because they have a lower mAh rating than most 1.5V cells. Internally they are made of 6 small 1.5V cells, imagine how small they’d be compared to even a AAA cell.

@PhilipHolden Do you have any specs on the lamps? If you do add it to your question. Thanks.

It will be easier to wire them in parallel. And probably more reliable too.  A flickering lamp doesn't draw a constant power, as the controller turns the LED on and off.  Wite two in series, and each flicker controller will try to flicker both lamps.
If you want the batteries to last, go a size up in 1.5V cells.  Or if re-using the battery holders, wire both in parallel (make sure you don't mix old and new batteries).
The other advantage of wiring them in parallel is that you can turn the LEDs on and off individually.
